# PHP “Could Not Access File:”

Tags: php

I am using this code in career.php page.

`Warning: file_get_contents(/home/eigeny6s/public_html/text.txt) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/eigeny6s/public_html/career.php`.

Also I had set permission to 0777 of public.html in ftp.

My code is:

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail,
                         $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message)
{


    $file = $path.$filename;
    print_r($file);
    $file_size = filesize($file);
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $content = fread($handle, $file_size);
    fclose($handle);
    $content = file_get_contents($strFilesName);
    $content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
    $header .= "--".$uid ."\n";  
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\n\n";  
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename ."\"\n";  
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";  
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename ."\"\n\n";  
    $header .= $content."\n\n";  
    $name = basename($file);
    $header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
    $header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
    $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."\n\n";  
    $header .= "E-mail: ".$_POST["email"]."\n\n";
    $header .= "Position: ".$_POST["position"]."\n\n";
    $header .= "Phone: ".$_POST["phone"]."\n\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
    $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
    $header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
    $header .= "--".$uid."--";

        if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
        echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
        } else {
        echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
        }
```

}

Comment: Forgive me if it's a dumb question, but did you check that the file `/home/eigeny6s/public_html/text.txt` actually exist? BTW, where does `$strFilesName` comes from? I can see where it's used, but I don't see where it's defined.

Comment: what path you are setting in `$strFilesName` and where is your file located?

Answer (score 0):

According to what you're describing, it's likely that the file `/home/eigeny6s/public_html/text.txt` doesn't exist.

Your code is trying to read this file, likely because that's what `$strFilesName` is.

To fix it you could:

- Ensure that this `text.txt` file exist
- or change the value of `$strFilesName`

Alternatively, if you can't guarantee that this file exist, you could check for it first:

```
$content = "default text used if I don't have my file";
if ( file_exists($strFilesName) ){
  $content = file_get_contents($strFilesName);
}
```